# from a xlsx file that contains links / references to xls raw data file

Tags: excel, save, xls, xlsx

I want to save my xlsx file that contains links to other worksheets, to a xls format that contains raw output without formulas..

Answer (score 1):

Would

```
Select all, Copy, Paste Values
```

Do it?

Comment: It's a start but it has multiple worksheets, so its a bit more clicking

Comment: Solved, i made a macro function

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Jaydee if the worksheets are in the same workbook - but remember to save as XLS first or you might accidentally lose the formula if you were intending to keep them in XLSX.

For multiple worksheets too. Simply click on the tab of the first worksheet, then the final worksheet while holding down the shift key. You can then select all on the first worksheet and it will automatically do the same for every other worksheet.

If you have links to worksheets in other workbooks (Excel files) use save as XLS then Edit Links & Break Links (data tab) will do the trick.